# What is happening when I use .scope() in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could someone please explain what is happening when I use .scope() inside of a directive?

I have a directive that is assigned to create a grid of squares. On load, I would like those squares to be clickable, so I have assigned

```
ng-click="disabled || add($index)"
```

and then in the `link: function () {}` I run:

```
scope.add = function (index) {
     scope.disabled = true;
}
```

so that all of them become disabled on click.

I then have a service that takes the index of one of the boxes that is clicked, runs some logic, and then brings back other possible squares that can be clickable. The service returns an array of indexes, e.g. `[2,5,6,7]`

I then take that array, loop through it, and assign those boxes to be clickable via their index:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var nScope = el.children().eq(arr[x]).scope();
    nScope.disabled = false;
}
```

Afterwards, when another one of the elements above is clicked, the original `scope.disabled = true;` is ignored, and the ones I setup above in the loop to be clickable, remain clickable... Why is that? What is happening when I run `.scope()` above and how do I refresh the grid to not be clickable again until the service comes back with more possible moves?

And, of course, if there is a more proper way of doing the above, please share.

EDIT:

Adding more code as requested in comments:

The HTML template:

```
<div 
    class="cell" 
    ng-click="disabled ||  addItem($index)" 
    ng-disabled="disabled" 
    ng-repeat="cell in ngModel.grid track by $index">{{item}}</div>
```

Settings for the directive are as follows:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'scripts/grid/grid.html',
    link: function () {
        //code above goes here
    }
}
```

The service has various things it is doing, one of which is to provide what possible objects can be clicked based on the index of the initially clicked object. For the purposes of this question, I left out the service code since my only issue so far is figuring out exactly what .scope() is doing and how I can use it to my advantage.

Comment: We need more code, what are your initial models settings? Are there any attributes passed by the directive? What is the purpose of the service? I don't think a name as generic as "disabled" is a good idea for a scope variable.It should be an attribute: a $scope.box = {status:"disabled"}. Concerning your error, you probably need what is called "isolated scope" for your directive. Google some tutorials on directives.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added some more code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This does not fully answer your question, but could be an approach for you to build upon.

See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4553/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.service('myService', function() {
    return{
        saveBox: function(id)
        {
        alert('gonna update box with id: '+id);
        }
    }
});


myApp.directive('boxgenerator', ['myService', function(myService) {
    return {
        template: '<div class="box {{status}} -  {{id}}">{{status}}</div>',
        scope:{
            id: '@id',
            status: '@status'
            },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) 
        {
            element.bind("click",function(){
               save = myService.saveBox(scope.id);
               scope.status = 'disabled'; 
               scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
}]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.boxes = [];
    $scope.box = { status: 'enabled' };

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
       $scope.boxes.push($scope.box);
    }
}
```

Maybe from this you can refactor in a more simple way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of that out and provide an example. What would be the best way to update what you have by making all of the boxes disabled (not just the one you click on) on the initial click and then enable a specific (random) box right afterwards? I ask because the scope is isolated (as it should be) so what would be the proper approach to access the global scope in the directive and disable all of the boxes once that click occurs. And once that happens, what would be the proper way to randomly turn on another one?

Comment: You're welcome, directives are perhaps the most difficult piece of AngularJS, and I'm still learning myself. In fact, I learned a bit while coding the example! For random, you probably have lots of vanilla JS scripts out there than can pick up a random entry in a JS Object ($scope.boxes). As for the inital click, you could keep track of the times the user has clicked by $broadcast(ing) the initial click in $rootScope. I must say, it's difficult to grasp the concept of your app... Are the disabled boxes still clickable, after the random one has been picked ? Is the enable box clickable as well?

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to wrap my head around all of it as well. At a "very" basic level, here's a codepen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vnLdt

Funny, the above took me like 5 min to do in jQuery. This angular interpretation has taken me much longer and all because I still have yet to understand scope.